# What form is 'numerārī'?

Tags: verbs, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, infinitive, passive-voice

In chapter X of Orberg's *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata* there is this sentence: *Piscēs numerārī nōn possunt.*

From the context I would translate this as an infinitive. But the infinitive should be numerāre. Perhaps it is a passive infinitive?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct, this is a passive infinitive: "to be counted".

The passive versions of *amāre*, *habēre*, *currere*, and *audīre* are *amārī*, *habērī*, *currī*, and *audīrī*.